go router don't route on deep link
I'm using go_router in flutter to handle deeplinks.
My issues is that I don't want to change the page when a deep link arrives but simply complete a Completer.
From what I can tell go_Router must always do a transition to another page.
The redirect property seems the closest but it looks like it still must route to either the redirect target or the original target.
So vaguely something like:
    GoRoute(
          path: '/xero/complete',
          redirect: (context, state) {
           /// if the state is correct then call the completer
            return isValid(state) ? xero.completer.complete() : null;
          },
          builder: (_, __) =>
              ErrorScreen()),

Help!
